# Class asks me to give self for Naive Bayes Model python

Tags: python, classification, prediction, naive-bayes-classifier, implementation

I try to use the following code but when I try to use fit function with `my X_train` and `y_train`, 
I get the following error:

`fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I do not know much about classes but I know it should not ask for `self`. I found somethings about instantiation but could not figure it out.

```
class BernoulliNB(object):
    def __init__(self, alpha=1.0):
        self.alpha = alpha

    def fit(self, X, y):
        count_sample = X.shape[0]
        # group by class
        separated = [[x for x, t in zip(X, y) if t == c] for c in np.unique(y)]
        # class prior
        self.class_log_prior_ = [np.log(len(i) / count_sample) for i in separated]
        # count of each word
        count = np.array([np.array(i).sum(axis=0) for i in separated]) + self.alpha

        smoothing = 2 * self.alpha
        # number of documents in each class + smoothing
        n_doc = np.array([len(i) + smoothing for i in separated])
        print(n_doc)

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.argmax(self.predict_log_proba(X), axis=1)
```

when I try

```
b = BernoulliNB() 
b.fit(b, X_train,y_train)
```

this time, I receive

```
fit() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Then I changed it to

```
BernoulliNB().fit(X_train,y_train)
```

but this time, this error occurs:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = BernoulliNB() 
b.fit(b, X_train,y_train)
```

This doesn't work because you're calling the fit method of the BernoulliNB class object you instantiated with BernoulliNB(). This argument says you have an extra parameter because it only accepts X, y.

It's hard to diagnose your second issue without seeing your data. But your y_train is probably formatted incorrectly.

Comment: I found an error on my y_train thanks to you @VictorNg and now my y_train is `y  -> 2400 non-null int64`
                                                                                                                                  unique values of y are: (1, 2)   but now I have following error when I try  `BernoulliNB().fit(X=X_train,y=y_real)`     the error is `cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: you still probably have a type error. if your y train is in a dataframe, you can use dtypes to get the type of the column and make sure it's correct. also, if this answer helped you, please accept it.